# CONVERTING MVC3 ASPX to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I converted my aspx views to razor using this utility http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/, it worked great except for this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<App.CourseApp.UI.Models.EditOffLine>>" %>
```

it was converted to:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.CourseApp.UI.Models.EditOffLine>
```

I get error validation (App.CourseApp.UI.Models.EditOffLine) is not supported with the green line under it; is this line correct?  also IEnumerable is not green?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is correct. Make sure you have referenced the project containing this `EditOffLine` class into your MVC application if it is in a separate project. Also try running your application to see if it works, never trust Intellisense in Razor views. Sometimes it might show something as an error where in reality it is correct and the application will run fine.